# css main background image with full height

Tags: html, css

Here is my tried css;

css:

```
.main
{
    width: 65%;
    background:url("../slice/body-bg.jpg");    
    display:block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0px;  
    min-height:100% !important;
    height:auto;     
    padding: 0px 12px;
}
```

Here is sample output screenshot: http://s18.postimg.org/q5zi9g7mh/untitled.jpg

I used in `html {height:100%;}` and

```
.main {min-height:100%; height:auto;}
```

But still it didn't work for me.

Can anybody help me to fix this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you add more code, and can you check what is the error on your console area, at developer tools, just press `f12` to see the dev tools.

Comment: Can you show us your html code? Where do you use .main class?

Comment: add background-size:cover in .main

Comment: in main class there are two sections..

Comment: @mmativ: I really don't think console errors are gonna pop up for css issues.

Comment: @Mr Bones Yes you can see in the console if the image path are wrong.

Comment: @mmativ I agree with you on that point, but personally, I don't consider file paths as css.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
html,
body{
    height:100%;
}

.main{
    height:100%;
}
```

Adding height:auto; after height:100%; superceeds it.

Comment: You need to show more code then.  There is something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

See example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqddooh2/)

HTML

```
<div class="main">123</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body{width:100%; height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `background-size:cover`

```
.main
    {

        background:url("../slice/body-bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;;  
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this purely through CSS thanks to the background-size property now in CSS3. We'll use the HTML element (better than the body as it's always, at least, the height of the browser window). We set a fixed and centered background on it, then adjust it's size using background-size set to the cover keyword.

**just try this:**

```
html { 
  background: url("../slice/body-bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I need to use background-image for main

Comment: so, i used your solution.. but i have sidebar.. that background image show for sidebar too.. i need to use  only for main..

Comment: instead applying for html,, try to apply for main ,, the same css

Comment: yes.. when i used in main.. again it stays same.. didn't show full height